# proxy for web server using jersey

Tags: web-services, proxy, jersey

i'm using jersey in my java client. is there a way to bring into the project server's representation, the server's proxy? like in web services basec jax-ws, where the client imports the wsdl and creates a proxy for server's objects and APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create WADL for your resources and then use wadl2java to create stubs/proxies.
To create WADL, see [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/WADL).
To use wadl2java see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6782099/162056).

I will warn you that:

1. The process is sparsely documented
2. I found the stubs are less helpful than jax-ws stubs due to the open nature of REST. E.g., a GET method with 2 parameters will have 4 methods representing it in the stub according to the 4 different ways you can call it - with both parameters, with first parameter only, with second parameter only and with no parameters.