# How to wadl2java these days?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, wadl

I have real difficulty finding commandline tool to convert WADL to java. No matter how much I try to google, follow blogs or java.net doc, there is no real download link. (links are broken or obsolete).

What particular vendor, community group is supplying this tool ? Does free download link exist ?

The generated code should be able to reconstruct POJOs from XML responses and survive inside Tomcat 7.
Thank you

**Answer: (this works only after June 2011):**

- Take Apache-CXF-2.4.1.zip (not any of the earlier versions)
- Extract it to root folder
- Take Apache-CXF-2.4.1.src.zip
- Search for folder named distribution inside src
- Extract ditribution folder and merge it with no overwrites to root folder
- goto bin and spot the wadl2java.bat
- run wadl2java.bat from command prompt
- continue with no brainer details

Comment: Do you mean WSDL?  Axis has a wsdl2java converter.  Axis2 is available here: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/.  The Java SDK also comes with wsgen.exe in $JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: Thank you, I have no problems with WSDL in SOAP camp. WADL is same sort of language for REST camp. Sort of forgotten minority of devs. Looks for me like abandoned and dying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) recently added support for [WADL-first development](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-WADLfirstDevelopment) of REST services. For more background information on its `wadl2java` tool, this [blog entry](http://sberyozkin.blogspot.com/2011/06/wadl-first-development-in-cxf.html) by one of the CXF committers should help.

Answer (score 7):

I had some trouble using the CXF 2.5.4 wadl2java tool. It kept complaining of a missing "resources" element in my WADL file, even though it contained one.

[wadl.java.net](http://wadl.java.net/) has a download of wadl2java that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an update with [CXF version 3.2.1](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cxf/3.2.1/apache-cxf-3.2.1.zip) it worked for me.

Steps are

1. Download anywhere
2. Unzip
3. Go to /bin
4. Run `wadl2java` to get the usage
5. Run `wadl2java -p com.x.y.z wadl-file.xml` to generate your classes in current directory.

By the way I noticed that it created a class with a space in the name and also created classes with name starting with digits :)

Answer (score 0):

As of Apache CXF version 2.7.11 just download the binary zip / tar.gz, set `CXF_HOME` env-var to `/path/to/apache-cxf-x.y.z` and wadl2java is available at `$CXF_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0):

For generating client side stubs from WADL, use a tool wadl2java. 
Download wadl tool from here:-
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jvnet/ws/wadl/wadl-dist/1.1.5/wadl-dist-1.1.5-bin.zip.

For genearting client side java stubs(POJOs), use this command: 
\wadl2java -o .\src -p com.test.client WADL_FILE_LOCATION

If you are using maven project then you can use wadl2java maven plugin for this work.